# Web workers debugging not available in developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, web-worker, developer-tools

All the tutorials I have seen about web workers talk about being able to debug them using developer tools. In Chrome developer tools on the Sources tab the accordion on the right hand side does not have "Workers". What do you have to do to enable it? I am using Version 44.0.2403.130 m.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to check workers here:
chrome://inspect/

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the section is titled "Threads".  Keep in mind that your web worker will only appear there during the time that it is running.